# How to print this manually made string

Tags: c++, string

I just needed to reverse a string, so I declared a new string variable and iteratively copied the elements. Now i want to print the reversed string through `cout << reversed;` but this is printing nothing. I can print it through a for loop through `reverse[i]` until the size but is there any better way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string original = "hello";
    string reverse;
    int i, j = 0, size = original.length();

    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) // original's last as reversed's first
    {
        reverse[j] = original[i]; 
        j++;
    }
    reverse[j] = '\0'; //last value as null
    cout << "original string = " << original << endl;
    cout << "reversed string = " << reverse  << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. `reverse` has a size of 0 and you are writing out of bounds.

Comment: ?? if i declare a string abc, then input cin >> abc. If i enter "what" then how can 4 chars fit into abc?
Plus i can print this reverse as
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        cout << reverse[i]; //and it works

Comment: `cin >> abc` resizes the `string` whereas your approach doesn't. `operator[]` doesn't allocate memory.

Comment: You're also not supposed to null-terminate `std::string` data yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reverse iterators to instantiate the reversed string from the original:

```
string original = "hello";
string reverse(original.rbegin(), original.rend());
```

Then

```
std::cout << "reversed string = " << reverse << std::endl;
```

Note: avoid `using namespace std;`. There is an algorithm called `std::reverse`, whose name you could be inadvertently pulling into the global namespace. And you do have a variable with that name.

See [this working demo](http://ideone.com/W5Jwbt).

Comment: thanks, ok. But what if i use namespace std and declared reverse123, it would've been fine right? Just in this case it could cause problems?

Comment: @ShoaibHaider It would be, but you cannot know that in the future there won't be an `std::reverse123` in the standard library. Just avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @faranwath It is certainly more efficient than the one involving `std::reverse` :-)

Comment: Ok my brothers and teachers, I am very thankful to all of you

Comment: @juanchopanza Certainly, but I thought `std::reverse` would be easier for him to understand.

Comment: @faranwath Yes, and it is a good algorithm to know in general.

Comment: @ShoaibHaider : Read this why `using namespace std;` is not considered as good practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @juanchopanza If I could +2 your answer, I would ;)

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to use `std::reverse`:

```
std::string original = "whatever";
std::string rev = original;
std::reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
```

Comment: Although, as it has been also pointed out by others, constructing the copy using reverse iterators is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem with your code is that `reverse` is empty, so using *any* index leads to you indexing out of bounds and undefined behavior.

As a side-note, you don't have to terminate `std::string` objects, they are automatically terminated.

Answer (score 1):

you should notice that **string reverse** doesn't have a size , so when you do something like this

```
for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) // original's last as reversed's first
{
    reverse[j] = original[i]; 
    j++;
}
```

Here, you are accessing an index that is not found in string reverse,as it's size is **0** . You should take care of something like that.

There are plenty of answers that your received about this question , I just wanted to make you notice this mistake

instead , you can make

```
reverse+=original[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to create a new string to hold the reversed string. Just iterator over the original string.

```
void print_reversed(const std::string& str)
{
    std::copy(str.crbegin(), str.crend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```